# SharedPreferences Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

So i am getting this errors after the MainActivity start.

```
04-04 17:30:37.041 7835-7835/net.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 17:30:37.041 7835-7835/net.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime: Process: net.example.ricardo.tcc2, PID: 7835
04-04 17:30:37.041 7835-7835/net.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {net.example.ricardo.tcc2/org.example.ricardo.tcc2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
04-04 17:30:37.041 7835-7835/net.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4008)
04-04 17:30:37.041 7835-7835/net.example.ricardo.tcc2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4039)
```

Using `SharedPreferences` to store facebook id and name.

onCreate i have this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("details", MODE_PRIVATE);

    nameStr = sharedPrefs.getString("name", null);
    idStr = sharedPrefs.getString("id", null);
```

onResume i have this:

```
public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
        profileImage = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.fotoPerfil);


        if (nameStr != null && idStr != null) {
            sessaoIniciada();
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am getting the correct name and id. Just cant set it to the txtview and profpicture.

Comment: Your `TextView` is null, double check that you're looking for the correct ID.

Comment: Add a check `if (username == null)` and print out a log statement in the if, your stacktrace is indicating that a `TextView` is null in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are getting a string from the String preferences you need the KEY and a default value. The default value cannot be null so set it to empty string or some random string

Modify like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("details", MODE_PRIVATE);

    nameStr = sharedPrefs.getString("name", "empty");
    idStr = sharedPrefs.getString("id", "empty");
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/597/545/full/erro.png?1459885481 its setting the text. but still getting the same error.

Comment: are you trying to set text in an ImageView?

Comment: no. its on the code.  String name, and String id. setText name and the id is for profileImage.setProfileId(idStr)....

Comment: why dont you pass the id as integer?

Comment: here is what it gets me. I have a facebook login activity. if i login and return to mainActivity, it displays the name and prof picture on the side_nav_menu. If i close the app and starts again. the facebook is still logged in. but not showing the picture nor the name. i want this sharedprefs to contain the name as string so i can set the name to te same textView again. and the id stored and string so i can set the id on a profilepicture id.

Comment: try like Integer.parseInt(idStr)